# Share links of a specific revision

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I see a big problem in the actuall linking of documentation into answers.

I will explain it at hand of an example which frustrated me this morning pretty much, so hopefully this doesn't appear like a rant.

We should have a option of linking to specific revisions of a document.

Otherwise it would happen that some one completly might rework an example and it isn't explaining anymore just a bit of an answer that linked it before.

The concret case was, I edited yesterday an example making references to the ISO documentation of C. To explain the concret example I did a lot of citing what took me multiple hours(!) to put in the correct explanations of the standard while trying to make it still understandable. I did this with the expectation to reuse it later for linking into my future answers.

But than a simple [edit of Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/52409) or [this one aswell](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/49507) just removed all my efforts of citing the primary source explanations by claiming they are wrong.

And also in the same edit he just removed a whole example as response for my request of improvement (Which was stated that it is an usefull example but the explanation needs to be less confusing). And this is also the third time I see Peter just removing full examples with some ordinary reasoning about it.

So for now I can say: I won't participate anymore in SO documentations by investing a lot of time, to make it a usefull knowledge collection, as long it only takes 2 persons regardless of their qualifications, to eliminate multiple hours a true professional did pony up, to make a clear and supported explanation to an example.

And even if I'm not interessted in participating yet anymore, I still would welcome it for 2 reasons if one could select the revision he would like to refer to.

- I'd like to refine my efforts put into that example at least to refer to it for my own future use so that it is not that it is even jsut 2 persons that can make my own content somewhat inaccesable even for my self.
- I can't see the sense in linking just the topic if it is changing its content so often. What made sense in context to my answer when I linked it, may have no sense anymore at all, just a few days later.

Comment: I had thought this would be accomplishable by clicking "view topic" in the revision list and grabbing the share link from there (as links taking users to certain timestamps of examples is _supposed_ to be a thing, but it may only be based on when the link was placed in something) but that proved fruitless. I agree we should be able to pick a specific revision to link to, similar to what can be done in SO post edit revisions list.